# Is there any package to implement arena or stadium seat map?

Tags: svg

Is there any **free** package for the arena or stadium seat maps? I need such a map to click, zoom in, zoom out, drag and drop. The following is an example [link](https://www.vividseats.com/yo-gotti-tickets-detroit-little-caesars-arena-5-20-2099/production/3356246) .

The main concern is about how to draw an SVG seat map.

[image: arena seat map]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [seats.io](https://www.seats.io/). They seem pretty good.